# How to get logs from a Jenkins plug-in during Maven based development?

Tags: maven, jenkins, logging

I am developing a Jenkins plug-in and want to see some logging.  I am using the Maven environment and running

```
mvn hpi:run
```

to launch Jenkins and my plug-in.  I have enabled the Jenkins logger configuration to catch my logs - but I see no logs less severe than INFO.
So I guess that I need to configure something to drop my debugging logs into wherever (syslog?) Jenkins pulls them from (I am asking Jenkins to pull `all` logs).

Can someone please explain how to do this via Maven? I have seen the 'How to set jenkins log level from maven?' article and tried those techniques but this seemed to cause Jenkins to hang, with messages about console restarts.

Please be very specific as I'm a relative Java newbie and would rather you treated me like an idiot than gave me only half an answer, assuming I knew the rest ;-).  Thanks!